# How to execute current MSbuild from cmake?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake

I want to build an application using `ExternalProject_add`. It has no CMake in and I have to use MSbuild. How to get MSbuild location for any given MSVC project generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a VS generator it sets a variable containing the used MSBuild (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_VS_MSBUILD_COMMAND.html).